# Is this proof about the Riemann integration correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

Can someone tell me if is this proof correct? I don't know if it is correct because I did it myself, so..

> If $f\in R$ on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is a monotonous function on $[a,b],$ then there exist $\epsilon \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^bfg=g(a)\int_a^{\epsilon}f+g(b)\int_{\epsilon}^bf.$$

Proof:

As $f\in R$ on $[a,b]$ then f is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Let $\alpha(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\alpha'(x)=f(x).$ So we have $d\alpha(x)=fd(x)$.

Now, by the second mean value theorem for riemann-stieltjes integrals*, we have $$\int_a^bfg=\int_a^bgd(\alpha)=g(a)\int_a^{\epsilon}f+g(b)\int_{\epsilon}^bf$$

This is the $*2nd$ MVT for riemann-stieltjes integrals:

Let $f$ be increasing on $[a,b]$, $g$ continuous on $[a,b]$. Then there exist $c\in [a,b]:\int_a^bfdg(x)=f(a)\int_a^cdg(x)+f(b)\int_c^bdg(x)$.

Comment: For $\alpha'=f$ you need $f$ is continuous. But to invoke 2ndMVT what you are using is the continuity of $\alpha$ which does happen (prove it or use if considered "well known"), and that $\int_{a}^{b}fg=\int_{a}^{b}gd(\alpha)$, which you could proof and add to your argument.

Comment: Maybe it is also good to add why $fg$ can be integrated. Since we only know that $g$ is monotonic and $f$ alone is integrable. Who knows, maybe the left hand side $\int_{a}^{b}fg$ doesn't exit.

Comment: yes I saw that f is not 'completely' continuous, how can I have f 'completely' continuous? and therefore to apply FTC @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: But what I was saying is that you didn't need it. And it is not given. So focus on what you actually need which is $\int fg=\int gd(\alpha)$.

Comment: why do I have the continuity of $\alpha$? I don't understand what do you mean with your hint for proving the continuity of $\alpha$ @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: I didn't give a hint for the continuity of $\alpha$. Actually, I haven't given any hints. I only listed the things that we need to complete the proof: We need continuity of $\alpha$ because $\alpha$ is playing the role of the $g$ in the 2ndMVT and in that statement the $g$ is assumed to be continuous. The other thing that we need is to prove that $\int fg=\int gd(\alpha)$. We need this because it is the first equation you wrote and the left hand side in the 2nMVT. Finally, we might need to show that $fg$ is integrable.

Comment: If you need a hint for proving the continuity of $\alpha$, try the definition: Write $|\alpha(x)-\alpha(y)|=|\int_{x}^{y}f|\leq\int_{x}^{y}|f|$. We want to show that this is small when $|x-y|$ is small. So, the interval of integration is small. ...

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy At this moment I'm already lost in this proof, maybe I should start again a new proof..

Comment: I think I'm understanding now , how can I make $\int_x^y|f|$ less than $\epsilon$ ? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: Since $f$ is Riemann integrable it should be bounded.

Comment: So $|f|\le M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ for $M>0$ . Thus $\int_x^y|f|\le M(y-x)$. And how do I define the $\epsilon$ ? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: Well, usually the $\epsilon$ is used as the name of the variable that you don't define. It is any *given* positive real number. The one that you define is the $\delta$. You can put $\delta=\epsilon/M$. Then if $\delta>|x-y|$ it follows that $\epsilon=\delta M>M|x-y|\leq |\int_{x}^{y}f|$.

Comment: And now how do I prove this $\int fg=\int gd(\alpha)$ ? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: please give me a hint ! @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: Using the definition of integrals (!?)

Comment: $\int fg=\int gd(\alpha)$ iff $f=d(\alpha)$? or idk what definition? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: The definition of integrals: $\int f = \lim\text{ of Riemann sums}$.

Comment: Do I start with the upper and lower sum of the right hand side or left hand side? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried. Probably either one works. On the other hand, I wonder whether it is worth it to go to all that trouble, just to show that one can use the theorem to prove a statement that is almost identical to the theorem. Instead I would just imitate the prove of the Theorem to prove the statement you want.

Comment: And detailed versions of the proof of that 2nd MVT can be found in many places, including this web site.

Comment: If $f$ were continuous then the proof finish. Don't you think? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy